# I am adding okta dependency in pom.xml file but the dependency is not resolving

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, oauth, microservices

I wanted to OAuth my microservice project, but the okta is not resolving.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.okta.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>okta-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Showing error: Dependency 'com.okta.spring:okta-spring-boot-starter:2.1.1' not found. My spring boot version is 2.7.9. I'm still not able to resolve the issue, can anyone suggest?

Comment: What's the _actual_ error message? Where is the dependency attempting to be downloaded from?

Answer (score -1):

It should be there:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.okta.spring/okta-spring-boot-starter

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.okta.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>okta-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Version 3.0.3 is most recent.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the project from the IDE and add once again. It worked for me.